# Best practices for executing specific JS scripts on on specific pages

Tags: javascript, oop, module

The title says it all. The project that I'm working on is not a single page application nor anything that implies any complex working with data flow or AJAX requests but I want to keep my code clean and avoid bugs as well as unnecessary evoking of functions that aren't going to be used on a page of the application, so I need to think over it's architecture.

Imagine that we declare namespace of an application:

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {}
```

Then I'm going to initialize a module that contains scripts using on that page:

```
var currentSection = w.location.pathname;

switch (currentSection) {
  case "/":
    return MYAPP._home = new _Home();
  case "contacts":
    return MYAPP._contacts = new _Contacts();
  default:
    return console.log('Unknown template');
}
```

In the example above I use part of URL to define which module is going to be used but I find it not really reliable because if we change URL then we also need to change some of piece of code accordingly otherwise it won't work. An another way of handling that is defining a template in a .php file, so it could be something like this:

```
<script>
  var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};
  MYAPP.template = 'contacts';
</script>
```

And slightly change that code that I used in the previous example:

```
switch (MYAPP.template) {
  case "/":
    return MYAPP._home = new _Home();
  case "contacts":
    return MYAPP._contacts = new _Contacts();
  default:
    return console.log('Unknown template');
}
```

Is there a better solution of the problem? We use Apache2 + PHP in back-end development if that information matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which module is going to be used

When you define a js file using `<script src=...`, the whole file and all its functions and classes in the file will be loaded. I don't see how you accomplish only loading one module or class using your code - I only see you are defining which objects are getting created.

This is how I specify which js files / classes are included. I use a three part process to include php, css, and js based on defines

In my `index.php` I have

```
define("module1", true);
define("module2", true);
require("includes.php");
```

My `includes.php` file is in the same dir as index.php (an also in the php path). In it I have:

```
<?php
require_once('paths.php');
if (defined("module1")){    
    require_once('module1.php');
?>
    <script src="<?php echo APP_PATH ?>/js/module1.min.js"></script>
<?php
} else if (defined("module2")) {    
    require_once('module2.php');
?>
    <script src="<?php echo APP_PATH ?>/js/module2.min.js"></script>
<?php
}
?>
```

in `paths.php`, which is located below root and in the php path, I have

```
<script>
    var APP_PATH = "www.mysite.com";
</script>
```

This way, the path info for my app is maintainable in one file. I also define my php paths in this file and prefix my php files, but that is beyond what you have asked.